# Change Visual Studio Code's title bar color

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the `Title Bar` color for Visual Studio Code (v1.26.0)?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

1. Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*
2. Look for `"window.titleBarStyle": "native"`, copy it to your user settings, and change it to `"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"`. It will adapt your theme now.
3. If the current color is not what you want or you want to tweak it, try doing this.
4. In your user settings, add the following.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Name of the Current Theme you are using]": {
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#191919cc",
    "titleBar.activeForeground":"#ffffff",
  },
},
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
```

Comment: I think, we also need to add the following:

`{
  "window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
}`

Comment: what about the background color and foreground of the menus that popup when you hover over file, edit, selection, etc...?

Comment: nevermind, I found them all in here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in VScode 1.30. I can't style the titlebar anymore. I used the Theme colors for the titlebar and menu in 1.29. Any suggestions?

Comment: It appears that `window.smoothScrollingWorkaround` isn't compatible with `window.titleBarStyle: custom` anymore: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63982#issuecomment-443356243

Comment: This is no longer correct. The other answer is correct

Comment: helped a lot, and VsCode suggested to use (with) the GTK Dark Title Bar and improved my workspace.

Comment: The second json layer is no longer needed in this section. See the following answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832821/284598

Comment: to have a different color for every project specific settings: edit the prj-folder/.vscode/setting.json   : add the  workbench.colorCustomizations config

    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#86f764cc"
    }

Answer (score 63):

[image: cmd palette]

Open menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* and add the following setting:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "titleBar.activeBackground": "#553955" // Change this color!
},
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
```

[image: result]

From the following source tutorial:

*[Colorful Visual Studio Code titlebars for better productivity](https://medium.com/@camdenb/colorful-vscode-titlebars-for-better-productivity-b05a619defed)*

Comment: This didn't work for me until I set `"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"` in the global user settings (I'm running Fedora 32 + KDE)

Answer (score 37):

There is now a handy Visual Studio Code marketplace plugin called *[Window Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors)* which automatically colors the ActivityBar and TitleBar of every window uniquely.

[image]

Just go to extensions and type: window colors

For more information, see the Visual Studio Code [marketplace webpage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors).

**Edit (Sept 2020)**: Just noticed that on Ubuntu 20.04 I had to set the `preferences->titlebar` setting from `native` to `custom` in the VSCode Preferences. Otherwise the titlebar does not change colors. Also see this [issue on github here](https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-peacock/issues/34)- the input from [@musicfuel](https://github.com/musicfuel) solved it for me.

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to add that how the color is chosen: `..."gives each new VS Code window a unique color based on a hash of the root directory name when it is opened..."`

Comment: Sadly it doesn't color the task bar icon.

Answer (score 16):

[**John Papa**](https://github.com/johnpapa) launched [**`Peacock`**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock) a few months back. I've been using the same since then.

It's an easy-to-use plugin with a great set of commands to work with.

It is highly customize-able.

Also it has emphasis on [**BrandColors**](https://brandcolors.net/) which comes in handy when you're simultaneously working on several different projects involving different frameworks and libraries.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I use it for coloring my Remote SSH windows to red (production server) to avoid accidental modifications in production code. I moved the plugin generated color settings from the project's `.vscode/settings.json` to `/home/myuser/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json` to make it default on that server (for any projects).

Answer (score 10):

In case somebody is still interested. I am using [Color Stamp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=s3anmorrow.color-stamp) extension.

For further tweaks, I changed the following parameters in my VSCode project settings:

`.vscode\settings.json`

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "titleBar.activeBackground": "#7C21D7",
  "titleBar.border": "#ebe8e8",
  "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#7c21d77c",
  "titleBar.activeForeground": "#ebe8e8",
  "statusBar.background": "#7C21D7",
  "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#7C21D7",
  "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#7C21D7",
  "statussBar.prominentBackground": "#7C21D7",
  "statusBar.foreground": "#ebe8e8"
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Please apply these simple steps.

1. Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*
2. Look for `"window.titleBarStyle": "native"`, and change it to `"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"`. It will adapt your theme now.
3. If the current color is not what you want or you want to tweak it, try doing this.
4. In your user settings, add the following.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "titleBar.activeBackground": "#191919cc",
  "titleBar.activeForeground":"#ffffff",
},
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that VSCode 1.45 (April 2020) will offer [additional settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/0446c8adad4a8aa6d5881f870a0af18f1f399731/release-notes/v1_45.md#new-theme-colors-for-editor-tabs):

> ### New theme colors for editor tabs
>
> Some **new colors** where added to further theme workbench editor tabs:
>
> - `tab.unfocusedInactiveBackground`: Inactive tab background color in an unfocused group
> - `tab.hoverForeground`: Tab foreground color when hovering
> - `tab.unfocusedHoverForeground`: Tab foreground color in an unfocused group when hovering
>
> ### New theme color for editor title border
>
> The existing color **`editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder`** changed to render a border below tabs but above breadcrumbs.
>
> A **new color `editorGroupHeader.border`** allows to render a border below the editor group header (i.e. below breadcrumbs if enabled) to restore the previous behaviour of `editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder`.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a simple Visual Studio Code plugin which accepts a list of regular expressions and colors and changes the titleBar based on them. It's great for working on [mono repositories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo) or large projects with multiple packages (like [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/), or [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) + [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native))

*[ColorTabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orepor.color-tabs-vscode-ext)*

Answer (score 2):

Changing the theme of Visual Studio Code will change the title bar color.

Menu File → Preferences → Color theme

Then switch to a different color theme, this will change the title color.