# VSCode Remove White File Menu on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

## My Question

I've been searching around and can't find a good answer to this question. Forgive me if I've missed it somewhere.

Does anyone know how to remove the white file menu in VSCode for Linux and make it black like it is by default on Windows?

## This is what I am referring to on Linux

[image]

[image]

## Conversely, this is what I see on Windows

[image]

[image]

## For reference, here is information regarding the software I am running:

### Windows

**OS Information:** Windows 10 2004 Build 19041.450

**VSCode Information:**

[image]

### Linux

**OS Information:** Debian 10 Stable, KDE Plasma Version 5.14.5

**VSCode Information:**

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just found an answer to this thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832770/change-visual-studio-codes-title-bar-color)

1. In the File menu, select *File -> Preferences -> Settings*
2. Search for `window.titlebarstyle`
3. Change `Window: Title Bar Style` to `custom`

Comment: Yeah, This works, i wonder if we could change this from vscode itself, why isn't its an default settings in the vscode, why would you want a native title bar anyways, while the custom vscode's is just better. Anyways Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I solved this long help problem for myself.., thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks ! Was looking for this for a long time and thought it was impossible...