# How to revert changes to Visual Studio Code Title Bar Color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed an extension and it changed my VS Code Title Bar Color and now I don't know how to fix it.

I want to change this:

[image: I want to change this]

I read other similar questions but it doesn't change at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Visual Studio Code's title bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832770/change-visual-studio-codes-title-bar-color)

Comment: Were you using the [Window Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors) extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the [Window Colors extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors), uninstalling it indeed does not revert the title bar colors.

You will have to go through all the workspaces you opened *while the extension was installed*, and:

1. Open **.vscode/settings.json**
2. Find the `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` block
3. Remove these three settings:

   ```json
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "activityBar.background": ...
       "titleBar.activeBackground": ...,
       "titleBar.activeForeground": ...
   }
   ```
4. Reload VS Code

If you have your own color customizations, then that block will contain other settings copied over from your User settings. Check that the extension indeed duplicates the color customizations from your User settings, then you can simply delete the entire `"workbench.colorCustomizations"` from the Workspace settings.