# How can you remove the border from the top tab bar of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to remove this border (regardless of what theme is used).

Other borders are removed and only this remains:

[image: border to remove]

Comment: If this gets reopened, I can answer with a solution that I believe should work.  I don't see why this was closed for being unclear.

Comment: @TimothyG. It's a duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395299/836330.  And yes, this shouldn't have been closed as unclear.

Comment: @Mark I don't think its a duplicate since the solution I believe is to set `breadcrumb.background: "#00000000"` which in turn will hide that line.  I don't think that question is quite the same, or at least it doesn't have this solution. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCF5j.png)

Comment: @TimothyG. The border is below the `editorGroupHeader` , changing the `breadcrumb.background` has no effect on that border.

Comment: @Mark unless I'm misunderstanding, the screenshot the OP posted is not pointing to the editorGroupHeader.

Comment: @TimothyG. So apparently it is unclear (although there is no border under the breadcrumbs to even try to point at...).  Especially the cursor arrow is pointing directly on the editorGroupHeader lower border.  @ali Set ` "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder": "#0000",` - you can indicate the hex color opacity with just 4 digits.

Comment: @TimothyG. My apologies - I misread it.  I blame the spurious extra characters for blinding me ;-).  I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @ali - Please include the configuration as *text*, though, in-addition-to-the-image.  The screenshot is, of course, necessary in this case, but we [also want the text for many reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).